# Can I assign a sound to everytime the mouse is clicked, in Flash AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

Seen a lot of sounds being played with buttons, or other ways, but is there any way of simply playing a sound clip when the mouse is clicked?

For instance if the sound clip was called 'laser' and was in the library?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a eventlistener with MousEvent.CLICK to the stage, and map it to a function in which you play that sound. here is a tut.

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3events/

Comment: Thank you!
For anyone else; I added a stage.mouseclick event, added a flash.media.sound import, gave my sound clip an AS linkage of Gunfire and made this function:

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gunsound);
    function gunsound (event:MouseEvent):void
    {
 trace("BOOM!");
 mySound.play();
    }